NextJS 14 and Vercel data cache, transform data before stored in fetch cache
I'm using an external API that returns a lot of data (as in more than 10x more than the data points I'm using).
I want to transform this data before it is stored in Vercel's data cache since it is using a lot of unnecessary cache read/write units.
Is there some way to hook into the fetch function and transform the data before it is stored in the cache?
